# AngularJS: Is it possible to access service value in app.run?

Tags: angularjs

My problem: I don't want users with a particular role typing in a valid URL for another page in the site and navigating there. I created a service to track the role. The role is set in the UsersController on login and console logs confirm it. Console logging shows the role is set properly everywhere, but I can never get access to it in app.run or app.config. I tried rootScope variables, event emitters, broadcasts, etc. But every time I type in a url the logging statements in app.run show the role is undefined. Help?

PS - Sorry the code's a little messy. I've been experimenting.

```
var app = angular.module('MainApp', ['ngRoute', 'ngMaterial']);

app.run(function ($rootScope, $location, $templateCache, roleAuthorization) {


    $rootScope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function () {
        $templateCache.removeAll();
    });

    $rootScope.$on('handleEmit', function (event, args) {
        console.log("handling emit");
        $rootScope.role = args.role;
        $rootScope.$broadcast('handleBroadcast', {role: args.role});
        roleAuthorization.setAuthRole(args.role);
    });

    $rootScope.$watch(function() { 
        return $location.path(); 
      },
      function(a){  
        console.log("Here we go: " + $rootScope.userRoleValue);
        if(a !== '/pharmacy/' && a !== '/users/login/' && a !== '/' && roleAuthorization.getAuthRole() === 'pharmacy'){

            window.location.href = '/pharmacy/';
        }
      });


});
app.service('roleAuthorization', function ($rootScope) {
    $rootScope.userRoleValue = '';
    this.getAuthRole = function () {
        return $rootScope.userRoleValue;
    };

    this.setAuthRole = function (x) {
        console.log("auth role set to " + x);
        $rootScope.userRoleValue = x;
        console.log('rootscope var is ' + $rootScope.userRoleValue);

    };

});
```

Comment: When the user types a URL in the location bar and hits Enter, the page reloads and the whole application restarts from scratch. So anything you've saved in memory at login time is gone, forever.

Comment: I wondered about that. Is there another method to be used?

Comment: That actually helped me quite a bit. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @JB Nizet for the inspiration. On page reload  we always get the current user, so I just needed to set it there as well for it to take and be available. Simple fix, in hindsight!

His comment: When the user types a URL in the location bar and hits Enter, the page reloads and the whole application restarts from scratch. So anything you've saved in memory at login time is gone, forever.